# How to manage and selectively stop a published subscription from Meteor server side code

Tags: meteor

I'm developing a competitive turn based game. When an anonymous visitor visits a page, he is automatically subscribing to a non-full instance of the game he can then either just observe or join the action. There are limited number of spots in each game instance. When joining the game (taking up a spot), the old subscription is stopped and new one is created that also includes private information based on his chosen spot. So far so good.

Now I want to make the server free up a spot whenever a player doesn't complete his turn in reasonable amount of time.

The question is how can I make sure the player kicked out of his spot no longer receives updates that are now intended to go to someone else occupying his spot? Obviously this has to happen on server side as clients cannot be trusted. Ideally the kicked out user would seamlessly become the observer again.

I know there is a method *stop()* that can be called inside *publish()*, but how to use it to stop a published subscription for one particular client when a callback set by *Meteor.setTimeout()* gets called on the server?

Some heavily modified code of what I'm trying to do (not meant to work, only to give you an idea)

```
  if Meteor.isClient
      publicGameHandle = Meteor.subscribe 'GameInstances'

      join = (gameInstanceId, spot) ->
          Meteor.call "join", gameInstanceId, spot, (err, guestId) ->
              Session.set("guestId", guestId)
              privateGameHandle = Meteor.subscribe 'GameInstances',
              gameInstanceId, spot, guestId, ->
                  publicGameHandle.stop()

   if Meteor.isServer
       privateSubscriptions = {}

       Meteor.publish 'GameInstances', (gameInstanceId, spot, guestId) ->
           if gameInstanceId
               GameInstances.find {_id: gameInstanceId}
               privateSubscriptions[guestId] = @
           else
               secretFields = {spots.guestId:false, spots.privateGameInfo:false}
               GameInstances.find {openSpots: {$gt: 0}}, {fields: secretFields}

       Meteor.methods({
           join: (gameInstanceId, spot) ->
               guestId = Random.id()
                   gameInstances[gameInstanceId].addPlayer(spot, guestId)
               guestId

           completePlayerTurn: (gameInstanceId, spot, guestId) ->
               gameInstance = gameInstances[gameInstanceId]
               Meteor.clearTimeout(gameInstance.timer)
               nextPlayer = gameInstance.getNextPlayer()

               kick = () ->
                   privateSubcriptions[nextPlayer.guestId].stop()
                   gameInstance.removePlayer(nextPlayer.guestId)
               gameinstance.timer = Meteor.setTimeout(kick, 60000)
```

Comment: My sense is that the designers of Meteor expect problems like this to be solved by changing the information that comes to each player through their subscription, and not by manipulating the # and open/close status of the actual subscriptions.

Comment: In that case I suppose I could completely split up public and private subscriptions so that each guest would subscribe to public game document in mongodb, plus get their own separate document that only they could subscribe to and that no longer get updates if the user is no longer in the game. Still would be nice to clean up old subscriptions that are no longer needed.

Comment: Or when publishing the subscription to the full game, the Meteor.publish function allows you to inspect this.userId and conditionally publish either an empty set, or the full game, depending on the user ID.  In the "Parties" example they do something like this, where Publish only publishes a subset of parties the user is invited to.  You can then use another collection to keep track of which users have a slot.

Comment: @JonathanWarden you only check this userId on the initial call to publish. You must do your own changes to the cursor. afterward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two separate subscriptions that both return game data.  One subscription should return public game data, the other should return game data that is viewable by the currentUser.  They will be merged into one collection on the client side. Games the user has joined will contain private info AND public info, games they haven't joined will only contain public info.  Then on the client side, a liveQuery like `Game.findOne(thisGame.id)` will automatically receive the private information when the player joins the game and cause your template to be re-rendered, etc.

Pseudo-code for illustrative purposes:

```
if Meteor.isClient
  Meteor.subscribe 'GameInstances'
  Meteor.subscribe 'MyGameInstances', guestId

  join = (gameInstanceId, spot) ->
      Meteor.call "join", gameInstanceId, spot, (err, guestId) ->
          Session.set("guestId", guestId)

if Meteor.isServer

   Meteor.publish 'GameInstances', () ->
       secretFields = {spots.guestId:false, spots.privateGameInfo:false}
       GameInstances.find {openSpots: {$gt: 0}}, {fields: secretFields}

   Meteor.publish 'MyGameInstances', (guestId) ->
       GameInstances.find {'spots.guestId': guestId}, {fields: secretFields}

   Meteor.methods({
       join: (gameInstanceId, spot) ->
           guestId = Random.id()
           gameInstances[gameInstanceId].addPlayer(spot, guestId)
           guestId

       completePlayerTurn: (gameInstanceId, spot, guestId) ->
           gameInstance = gameInstances[gameInstanceId]
           Meteor.clearTimeout(gameInstance.timer)
           nextPlayer = gameInstance.getNextPlayer()

           kick = () ->
               gameInstance.removePlayer(nextPlayer.guestId)
           gameinstance.timer = Meteor.setTimeout(kick, 60000)
```

It sounds like you might be including many players private info on one Game Instance. So that will be harder to filter the fields that are allowed (and only publish the CURRENT guest's private info, without publishing other players' private info).

In that case, you might consider either:

- refactor private info into a separate collection, and publish it as a separate subscription
- custom publish function. Here's an example:

https://gist.github.com/colllin/8321227

In this code, I'm observing one collection and publishing data that will be merged into the `Meteor.users` collection.  You can see that the subscription is publishing data like `{_id: userId, wins: 25}`, which makes a `wins` field available on user models on the client side.  You will probably want to `observe()` the Games collection but manually filter the private data based on the current user, then publish that private data into the Games collection to be merged with the public data.  You can pass in the `guestId` to the publish function like you did above.